# Redireccionar a url al hacer click (settimeout)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando hacer una funcion en js para que cuando el usuario **haga clic en un enlace** pasen unos segundos y automaticamente **redireccione a otra url.**

```js
function redireccionarPagina() {
  window.location = "http:/#";
}
setTimeout("redireccionarPagina()", 2000);
```

```html
<a href="hielo-fuego.html" id="texto_mar" onmouseover="mouseOverMar()" onmouseout="mouseOutMar()">
  <img title="Mar" src="css/images/mar_text_white.png" onclick="reload()" />
</a>
<a id="maria">
  <img title="Mar_basic" src="css/images/o_basic.png" />
</a>
<a href="hielo-fuego.html" id="texto_tierra" onmouseover="mouseOverTierra()" onmouseout="mouseOutTierra()">
  <img title="Tierra" src="css/images/tierra_text_white.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Pues que no se como hacer para que cuando el usuario haga clic en el enlace, pasen X segundos y luego redireccione a una url. @PabloLozano Lozano

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que detectar el click, anular el comportamiento por defecto, y entonces hacer el setTimeout:

```js
let a=document.getElementById('enlace');
a.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //esto cancela el comportamiento del click
  setTimeout(()=> location.href="https://www.google.com",1000);
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="enlace">Ir a google.com en un segundo</a>
```

El ejemplo no se ejecutará porque StackOverflow no lo permite en el código de las respuestas, pero debería funcionarte perfectamente.

Comment: Estoy intentando esto y me escupe el siguiente error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null ¿qué puede fallar?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que a cualquiera de tus enlaces que le den, se redireccione a una url, te recomiendo asignarle a todos tus enlaces un evento para que cuando le den clic a cada uno de ellos, se redireccione a la url en cuestión.

Para ello, puedes asignarle la función `addEventListener` a cada uno de tus enlaces, utilizando la función `setTimeout` dentro de la misma para esperar 2 segundos desde que le das clic hasta que se muestra la página.

Ejemplo:

```js
var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
    enlaces[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          window.open("https://www.google.es")
      }, 2000);
    });
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Esto es un link</a>
<a href="#">Esto es otro link</a>
<a href="#">Esto es otro link</a>
```

Comment: Lo estoy usando pero no funciona, si el enlace está dentro de algun div eso puede ser un problema?

Comment: ¿Te da algún tipo de error en la consola?

Comment: La consola no refleja ningun mensaje de error.

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez ¿Lo que quieres mostrar es la url dentro del div? ¿O en una página diferente?

Comment: Quiero que cuando se haga clic en el enlace pasen dos segundos y seguidamente cargue la nueva url.

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez He cambiado la función ya que con `windows.location` para la página de Google me daba un error:  `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`. En principio con esta nueva función no te tendría que dar ningún problema. Aquí en Stackoverflow en español está bloqueado para que no puedas abrir páginas externas pero en tu servidor no te tendría que dar ningún problema.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, me dice que no puede leer la propedad length. Se podria hacer mejor llamando al id del enlace? var enlaces = document.getElementById("texto_mar_movil");


    enlaces.addEventListener("click", function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          window.open("https://www.google.es")
      }, 2000);
    });
..seria algo asi creo pero esta incompleto verdad?

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez Fíjate que en mi caso estoy obteniendo todos los elementos `a` que haya en la página, es decir, todos los links. Por eso hago un bucle `for`, para ir recorriendo cada uno de ellos. En tu ejemplo solo funcionaría para el enlace con ese ID. También ten en cuenta que yo estoy poniendo el protocolo `https` y tu no en la URL, puede que falle por ese motivo.

Comment: gracias por ayudarme Francisco pero sigue sin funcionar incluso sin https, es que no hace intención de ir hacia el enlace es como si no lo detectase, tampoco da errores en la consola.

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez Mira, he creado un JSFiddle externo, dónde si se permite abrir pestañas nuevas. Lo puedes ver [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/ew1r7gba/)

Comment: Al final lo he hecho añadiendo esto: 
    setTimeout(()=> location.href="http://paginaprueba.es/mariadelao/hielo-fuego.html",2200);
} a la funcion Gracias!, no sé porque no me funcionaba el tuyo, pero ya lo tengo ahi para la proxima

Comment: @AntonioÁngelEstradaPérez No se ve nada.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `setTimeout` para esperar el tiempo que necesites y llama a la función que abra la URL.

```js
function redireccionarPagina(){
    window.setTimeout( abrirURL, 3000 ); // 3 segundos
};
    
function abrirURL(){
    //Abrir URL que necesites
    console.log("Han pasado 3 segundos");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redireccionarPagina()">Abrir</a>
```

Comment: como pongo la url asi?:  location.href="https://www.google.com";

Answer (score 1):

Con JQuery quedaría así

```js
$(document).on("click","#toGoogle",function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "https://www.google.com.mx"; }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toGoogle">Link<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mouseOverTierra_movil() {
    document.getElementById("texto_mar_movil").innerHTML = '<img src="css/images/mar_text_nowhite.png" />';
    document.getElementById("texto_tierra_movil").innerHTML = '<img src="css/images/tierra_text_white.png" />';
    document.getElementById("maria_movil").innerHTML = '<img style="max-width:85%;" src="css/images/tierra_img.png" />';
    setTimeout(()=> location.href="http://paginaprueba.es/mariadelao/hielo-fuego.html",2200);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="texto_mar_movil" onmouseover="mouseOverMar_movil()"><img title="Mar" src="css/images/mar_text_white.png"/></a>
```